# Concat two dictionaries so that original's shared keys are updated

Tags: c#

Say I have two dictionaries:

```
Dictionary<string, string> orig = new Dictionary <string, string>();
orig.Add("one", "value one");
orig.Add("two", "");
orig.Add("three", "");

Dictionary<string, string> newDict = new Dictionary <string, string>();
newDict.Add("one", "this value should not be added");
newDict.Add("two", "value two");
newDict.Add("three", "value three");
```

How can I merge the two dictionaries so that the resulting dictionary updates the keys only where their corresponding values are empty? Additionally, the merge should not add any keys that are present in `new` but not in `orig`. That is, "one" still has the value "value one" while "two" and "three" are updated with the values from `new`.

I tried using `orig.Concat(new);`, but that leaves me with the original dictionary. Perhaps this can be done with LINQ?

Comment: This cannot be done with LINQ.

Comment: @SLaks Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: LINQ is about _queries_; it cannot mutate existing objects.

Comment: @SLaks I am fairly certain that it can. And by assigning the result of a Query to an existing object, you can mutate it.

Comment: @bolucpapuccuoglu  it can but doing so is a bad idea. Use queries as queries, not updates.

Comment: @SLaks: I would say that extension methods like `ToList()`, `ToArray()` and, relevant to this question, `ToDictionary()` are part of LINQ.

Comment: @MartinLiversage: Those create new objects; they don't mutate existing objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
orig = orig.Keys.ToDictionary(c => c, c=>(orig[c] == "" ? newDict[c] : orig[c]));
```

Comment: This should also check to ensure the key exists in the second dictionary.

Comment: @Servy, you are right, but I inferred from the example that the OP gave that the two dictionaries have matching key collections. My reason for that inference was the existence of empty string values in the orig dictionary. tnw, if there is a possibility that the two dictionaries don't have matching key collections, please say so, and I will modify my answer code.

Comment: @BolucPapuccuoglu A correct inference, so this suits my specific use case. Servy would be correct, however, for a broader solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

This loop does what you want efficiently and readable:

```
Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var keyVal in orig)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyVal.Value))
        result.Add(keyVal.Key, keyVal.Value);
    else
    {
        string val2;
        if (newDict.TryGetValue(keyVal.Key, out val2))
            result.Add(keyVal.Key, val2);
        else
            result.Add(keyVal.Key, "");
    }
}
```

Result:

```
one, value one  
two, value two
three, value three
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `foreach`

```
foreach (var pair in orig.Where(x=> string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Value)).ToArray())
{
    orig[pair.Key] = newone[pair.Key];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Extension method 'one-liners' are great when they help to clarify intention, but for something like this, I would be inclined to write a small method with an explicit loop that does the desired operation.  I think this is much cleaner than creating a new dictionary using various extension method transformations:

```
    public void PopulateMissingValues(Dictionary<string, string> orig, Dictionary<string, string> newDict)
    {
        foreach (var pair in orig.Where(p => p.Value == string.Empty))
        {
            string newValue;
            if (newDict.TryGetValue(pair.Key, out newValue))
                orig[pair.Key] = newValue;
        }
    }
```